# Primeng range calender output issue

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng-calendar

I want to format the output of the Primeng **Range** Calender for both dates to be 'dd/MM/yyyy' like this, and I tried to use pipe to transform the these data. But is only only transforming the first date, and not the second. Html code is:

```
<div>{{rangeDates | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</div>
```

Ts file is:

```
  rangeDates: Date[];
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Mon Dec 02 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time),Tue Dec 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let range of rangeDates"">
    {{range | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
</div>
```